# Android: ViewPager setCurrentItem() method not work after onPause()

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int i)` to change page of the a ViewPager with two pages, I'll call them page 0 and 1, but it seems not work after the activity `onPause()` caused by android device's screen off.

Here is my scenario:

1. change the viewpager to **page 1** in `onPause()`
2. change back to **page 0** after 5 seconds (activity in background)
3. when come back, I want the viewpager showing **page 0**

Strange result:

1. when I jumped to another activity and came back after 5 seconds, it worked well, i got **page 0**
2. when I turned off the screen and turned on after 5 seconds, i got **page 1**, even the pageChangeListener told me that the pager had already selected 0

I want to know the real reason or some details about the difference between these two results. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

It looks like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316729/android-viewpager-setcurrentitem-not-working-after-onresume), but it's not exactly what i want to kown and not the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you in your `onPause`:

`yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(MAX_POSSIBLE_PAGES);`

Basically, it forces the pager to retain all possible pages when idling. That way, when you resume, your indices for `setCurrentItem()` make sense.

Comment: not work, it seems that screen's turn off affect the view's rending a lot. Is it right?