# onItemClick in list doesnot open selected item in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-sqlite

onItemClick doesnot open selected item in viewpager

I have a list view which is populated using a sqlite db with a helperclass

when we click on a item in listview it should open the viewpager class and we can swipe through various details

the viewpager opens but always starts from the first list item

even though I have set the

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int index = b.getInt("position");
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

I want to open the viewpager with the item that I have selected and not start from the first entry each time.

here is the listactivity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ListView listView;

    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aa" + position, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), viepagerActivity.class));
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, viepagerActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                MyActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this,
                        databaseHelper.getAllData());
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EnterDataActivity.class),
                ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            databaseHelper.insertData(
                    data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"), data
                            .getExtras().getString("tag_person_pin"));

            customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
        }
    }
}
```

adapter

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

        TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_person_name);
        textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

        TextView textViewPersonPIN = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_person_pin);
        textViewPersonPIN.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                .getColumnName(2))));
    }
}
```

The viewpager

```
public class viepagerActivity extends Activity {

    private List<String> testContactName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> testContactNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int index = b.getInt("position");

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "viepager" + index, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        try {
            getAllContacts();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public void getAllContacts() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.database;
        String[] columns = { PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID,
                PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME,
                PersonDatabaseHelper.PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(PersonDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null, null);


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                    .getColumnName(1)));
            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                    .getColumnName(2)));

            testContactName.add(name);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            testContactNumber.add(phoneNumber);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        cursor.close();
    }


    private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter() {

            super();

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return testContactName.size();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View collection, Object object) {

            return collection == ((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_items, null);

            TextView contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelText);
            TextView contactNumber = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.answerText);


                try {
                     contactName.setText(testContactName.get(position));
                     contactNumber.setText(testContactNumber.get(position));

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }


}
```

the helper class

```
public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

    public static final String TAG = PersonDatabaseHelper.class
            .getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table"; // Table name
    public static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id"; // a column
                                                                // named "_id"
                                                                // is required
                                                                // for cursor
    public static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
    public static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN = "person_pin";

    public DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will
    // communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform
    // database CRUD operations
    public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData(String aPersonName, String aPersonPin) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
        contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN, aPersonPin);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }

    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database
    // related operation

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_PIN + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL); // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase); // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316729/android-viewpager-setcurrentitem-not-working-after-onresume

Comment: strangely that worked thanks

Comment: will it work with latge data say 5000 records

Comment: Try it see what you get. I haven't tried it with large number of records