# ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener giving wrong position

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

In a fragment i'm using a ViewPager and setting a current item.

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
mViewPager.setAdapter(someAdapter);
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Now, OnPageChangeListener's method "onPageSelected(int position)" is not giving positon value 4 or 6, but giving 1. I want if current position is set to 10 then position parameter give 11.

Answer (score 1):

Your are writing correct code but not in correct order.

```
 mViewPager.setAdapter(someAdapter);
 mViewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

you should first set the `adapter` then tell which position to load in `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `setCurrentItem()` only after calling `setAdapter()` **and** wait for the viewpager to complete its loading.  There seems no proper way of doing this.  A hack is to wait some milliseconds before calling `setCurrentItem()` -

Reference: [Android ViewPager setCurrentItem not working after onResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316729/android-viewpager-setcurrentitem-not-working-after-onresume)

An alternative is to call `setCurrentItem()` in an `OnLayoutChangeListener` -

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=75309