# Viewpager setCurrentItem() method don't work normally after activity jump in "don't keep activity" develop option

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I turn on the **"don't keep activity"** develop option.
In activity A,there is a viewpager.
Then Activity a jump to Activity B, then press back button return to A,this time viewpager's  setCurrentItem() method don't work normally.Unnormally means **don't trigger onPageSelected() method in ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener**,and at the same time the related Tablayout don't perform right.
I've tried call the method in viewpager.post() (the solution written in other post in stackoverflow,[like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316729/android-viewpager-setcurrentitem-not-working-after-onresume)).
By the way,i use Android Annotation,and i call the setCurrentItem() in @AfterViews.

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: @Nigam Patro You mean the related solution post? I've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this code:
@Override
void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
    if (savedInstanceBundle != null){
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceBundle.getInt(VIEWPAGER_PAGE);
    }
}
    @Override
void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    // Put your current ViewPager Page here;
    outState.putInt(VIEWPAGER_PAGE, page));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've find the reason.
It caused by the ViewPager's onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.
I don't know the detailed reason now, i'll post the detailed answer when i know.