# How to show fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager to create 3 Fragment on Activity1,
this is my viewPager adapter :

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 tab1 = new Fragment1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment2 tab2 = new Fragment2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Fragment3 tab3 = new Fragment3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }

}
```

this is Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

    TabLayout tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag1"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag2"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Frag3"));

    final ViewPager view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tab_layout.getTabCount());

    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

}
```

When Activity1 is open it show Fragment1 . But I want to show Fragment2 or Fragment3 instead .
How I can to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line after `viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);` :

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

Index is depending on you , how many fragments you have. `tabLayout.getTabCount();` will return you tab count. But index is starting from 0.

If you have 3 `Fragment` and want to show third `Fragment` you must use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);`

Comment: @1234abcd no problem , i think you got what is index !

Answer (score 1):

Set current position of viewpager to your desired possition which is 2 or 3 in your case.

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(desiredPos);
                }
            });
```

seee more

[Android ViewPager setCurrentItem not working after onResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316729/android-viewpager-setcurrentitem-not-working-after-onresume)